# Editing and saving files like FileZilla FTP

Tags: php, mysql, html, ftp, ftp-client

I'm needing help on a starting point of a project (if possible).

**What I'm looking to do**: Have a part of a website that contains files (done). They will all be Excel files. A user can open the file (double-click or right-click -> open), make some edits, save the file and this will be updated on the server. Looking for something very similar to how you edit files through FileZilla FTP.

**Where I am confused**: What is the terminology I would use to search for assistance on how to operate this? I have searched SO for 'custom FTP' and the like, however I think this is incorrect. I'm missing/confused on what is needed for communicating with the server.

**What I have tried**: I built the page containing the files. The page holds a bunch of file names and has links to download/open. The HREF is the location of the file on the server. It downloads fine but when saving the opened file, it only saves locally and not on the server. What else should I include so the edits are saved on the server?

Example of a file on the site:
`<a href="path_to_file_location.xls" download="File name">File name</a>`

Any links or verbiage to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if further information is needed. Thank you!

Comment: is a bit offtopic, but either way, what you want is to create a editor google drive style? or just open a ftp protocol from the url?

Comment: One method is to use a CMS. However, you've shown `xls` type of files. Being Excel, you may need to use an add-on for this.

Comment: @jycr753 I think google drive is a fair comparison but opening an ftp protocol from the url sounds a bit more accurate. I suspect the google drive bit is overkill for what I need to do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm currently on the CMS MODX. How exactly does using a CMS correlate to the ability to remote edit files? Or does CMS mean something else? I'll start looking into MODX to see if they have something already in their library to fit this!

Comment: well google chrome does support ftp connection, but it will be as if you had in filezilla... I mean you could create a draw and drop after the file has been downloaded,... and use this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335236/uploading-file-through-ftp-using-php or also here

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php but again, it maybe a lot work to do.. so happy coding :)

Comment: ok, this is the part I was missing I think. I wasn't aware of the FTP options in PHP. I've got some reading to do, thanks for the links!

Comment: CMS = Content Management System. Those can allow you to add (registered) users to edit content on-the-fly. I can't remember which ones (off the top of my head) that do allow it, but there are some; I've seen them before. Another method would be to use Wordpress and to make people admins, or content creators. @ride_85027 - Plus, as already mentioned, FTP/PHP is another method.

Comment: Changing the CMS at this point would be very difficult (this portion of the site is simply that -- a portion). But I'm still looking into possibilities that involve MODx offering this 'feature'. May end up just going the FTP/PHP route. Thank you @Fred-ii- for your input, it's greatly appreciated and helpful!